# How to Create a List of Different Dimensioned Arrays C# - Minimax Algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, chess, minimax

I'm trying to create a simple chess AI and I'm currently implementing the minimax algorithm. My goal is to have an array (or list, whatever datatype really) of `Board` objects, each row containing one more dimension than the other. Here's kind of an idea of what I want:

```
[
board,
[boardA, boardB],
[[boardAA, boardAB], [boardBA, boardBB]]
...
]
```

This would be pretty simple if I wanted a to search to a fixed depth, but I want a variable depth which is more complicated. Is there an elegant way to do this? My current method just puts all the boards in a single array, which is good for counting elements, but makes it much harder to do any other minimax operations. Thanks for any help!
Here's my current implementation:

```
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int length = 1;
        depth++;
        Board[][] ret = new Board[depth][];
        ret[0] = new Board[] { board };
        Board[] tempBoard = null;
        Board[] largeTemp= null;
        int[][][] temp;
        for (int i= 0; i<ret.Length-1; i++)
        {
            length *= 30;
            largeTemp = new Board[length];
            for (int j=0; j < ret[i].Length; j++)
            {
                temp = ret[i][j].allMovesDescript(who);

                tempBoard = new Board[realLength(temp)];
                for (int x = 0; x < temp.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (temp[x] == null) continue;
                    tempBoard[x] = ret[i][j].copy();
                    tempBoard[x].move(temp[x][0], temp[x][1]);
                }
                board.concatList(largeTemp, tempBoard);
            }
            largeTemp = shorten(largeTemp);
            ret[i + 1] = largeTemp;
            who = !who;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("It took " + milliseconds(watch.Elapsed.ToString()) + " ms to look " + (depth-1) + " move(s) into the future. \nThere are " + realLength(ret[depth-1]) + " possible situations after " + (depth-1) + " move(s).");
        return ret;
```

Comment: At first glance, it sounds like you want an array of arrays, which is called a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), and which you initialize like: `board[][] boards = new board[rowCount][];`

Comment: Aside: the minimax algorithm by itself does not require game positions to be saved.